# Does momentum change if rotation radius changes?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, momentum

Angular momentum is defined as $L = r \times p$ where r is the center of rotation and p is the momentum. Since angular momentum is conserved, if r decreases then p must increase. And since p is m*v the velocity must increase. But that would change the momentum while keeping the angular momentum constant. Aren't both angular and linear momentum supposed to be conserved unless acted upon by an external force?

Comment: What makes $r$ decrease?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular momentum is conserved. If you have ever been in an office rolly-chair, you might (admit it) have spun around in it. If you stick out your legs, you will actually slow down. If you tuck them in, you will speed up.

This is just a consequence of the equation $$L = r \times p$$

Since $L$ is conserved, as $r$ -> $0$, $p$ -> $\infty$, and as $r$ -> $0$, $p$ -> $\infty$

Therefore, these forms of momentum are still conserved. This is only why an ice skater spins faster when they tuck their feet and arms together, and they slow down when they stick a leg out.

Comment: So the momentum changes as the ice skater moves his arms in and out, yet it is conserved? Would you mind elaborating on that?

Comment: @lawls The angular momentum is conserved. I see. I messed up in the answer. edited

Comment: Hm, but isn't momentum supposed to be conserved too? I don't see what I'm missing.

Comment: @lawls You have changed the system.

Comment: @lawls Just to clear things up, the linear momentum, as Mukhopadhyay pointed out is NOT conserved for change in radius. Of course it is conserved (and just the total momentum) if the radius does not change (and there's no dissipation, like friction). The angular momentum, however is always conserved in a central field of force, no matter if the central force is external or internal. So when you change the radius, you change it with a central force field (you pull back towards the center), thus angular momentum conservation is true, but it is an external force that changes linear momentum.

Comment: @lawls Oh, sorry, the central force field is not nessecarily external. Consider the following two situations: the ice skater in Jimmy360-s example is spinning with her arms spread out. She may be practically considered as two point masses spinning around an axis. First she pulls back one of her arms (one point gets close to the axis). This was done by a central force, and due to action-reaction principle, her body should have moved towards her hands, but her skeletal muscles have held her body back. Her skeletal muscles have held her back against the ground, which keeps the axis in place

Comment: defined by the tip of her skate digging into the ice. This way, through her body, an external force acted upon one of the point masses (which originally came from the ground as a force keepeing the axis in place as a constraint). This way the angular momentum does not change, the linear momentum however does. In the second case, she pulls both her arms back. The force with which she pulled one arm back has to have a reaction force, but this force now pulls the other arm back (again through her body), so no external force acts upon her. This way both angular and linear momenta are conserved.